# How to make background of table cell transparent

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am creating a table inside a table for my "all users" page. The first table was divided in to two parts--the ads and the users--. Inside the "users" table under `<tr><td>...</td></tr>`, I created another table for each of the user's data to appear via php.

Here's the image : http://postimg.org/image/3mbeyb411/

As you can see in the image, the right side of the parent table (which is larger than the left one) contained the "users" table where their profile pictures appeared which is good.

Now I put this nice blurry background on my page but the *parent table's white cell background* is blocking it.

How can I make that white background become transparent? I tried doing the `background:transparent;` but to no avail.

```
<table id = "MainTable">
  <tr>
    <td width = "20%">
      
     </td>

    <td width = "80%">
        <table.......>***php users appear code here***</table>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And for CSS

```
#MainTable {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D8F0DA;
    border: 1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.97;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Please I really need your help. I've been Googling this for days and still didn't find a single answer

## UPDATE

What I was looking for is something like this `<td style="background:transparent;">` but still I didn't find it on the web. Or is it even possible to make the table and the cell's background transparent?

Comment: `<tr style="background-color: #ffffff;"></tr>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transparent background will help you see what behind the element, in this case what behind your `td` is in fact the parent table. So we have no way to achieve what you want using pure CSS. Even using script can't solve it in a direct way. We can just have a workaround using script based on the idea of using the same background for both the body and the `td`. However we have to update the `background-position` accordingly whenver the window is resized. Here is the code you can use with the default background position of `body` (which is `left top`, otherwise you have to change the code to update the `background-position` of the `td` correctly):

**HTML**:

```html
<table id = "MainTable">
 <tr> 
    <td width = "20%"></td>
    <td width = "80%" id='test'>
      <table>
        <tr><td>something interesting here</td></tr>
        <tr><td>another thing also interesting out there</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```css
/* use the same background for the td #test and the body */
#test {
  padding:40px;
  background:url('http://placekitten.com/800/500');    
}
body {
  background:url('http://placekitten.com/800/500');
}
```

**JS** (better use *jQuery*):

```js
//code placed in onload event handler
function updateBackgroundPos(){
  var pos = $('#test').offset();
  $('#test').css('background-position', 
                            -pos.left + 'px' + " " + (-pos.top + 'px'));
};
updateBackgroundPos();
$(window).resize(updateBackgroundPos);
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/uPs4W/1)

Try resizing the viewport, you'll see the `background-position` updated correctly, which will make an effect looking like the background of the `td` is transparent **to the body**.

Answer (score 25):

You can do it setting the transparency via style right within the table tag:

```
<table id="Main table" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
```

The last digit in the rgba function is for transparency. 1 means 100% opaque, while 0 stands for 100% transparent.

Answer (score 4):

**It is possible** 
 You just also need to apply the color to '*tbody*' element as that's the table body that's been causing our trouble by peeking underneath.
`table, tbody, tr, th, td{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) !important;
}`

Answer (score 3):

What is this? :)

```
background-color: #D8F0DA;
```

Try

```
 background: none
```

And override works only if property is exactly the same.

background doesn't override background-color.

If you want alpha transparency, then use something like this

```
background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but the background of the table became transparent.. what I meant was the 'background of the cells will became transparent'.... I tried creating a transparent image in photoshop and set it the background-image but still, the cells are still white -.-

Comment: If you use background image then don't use background color. And if you want to use opacity then I suggest you to use RGBA alpha value 0.97 as in my example. But you want something less than 0.97 I guess.

Comment: So you want whole table have background, but cell should be transparent?  Sounds like Portal game to me. No way you can do it in css.

Comment: So what can you suggest ?

Comment: Table borders maybe. Maybe I just don't understand your question.

Comment: Actually, you could put background image you use as page background for cell and use background-position: fixed; It will work, but it's a bit dumb way. And! Use divs not tables. Tables are for tabular data not for layouts.

Comment: Wow I think u just gave me a hint in there. Okay so the truth is I want two table display side-by-side like you see in the image I just posted but since I couldn't do it (they always align themselves vertically not horizantally), I created a table and put two tables in there then wanted to set the main table transparent.. I know its kinda dumb but I like to improvise lol.. maybe you can help me with that side-by-side table ?

Comment: why dont you use columns and within one table? I kind of got feeling you have no idea what are you doing and if you don't then try to do it with css and divs. Learn to do it properly from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I use the **"transparent"** keyword and it works perfect!

```
<style type="text/css">
#img table,tr, td {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    align="center";
    border-spacing: 25px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving colour to the background and then expecting it to be transparent?
Remove `background-color: #D8F0DA`,

If you want #D8F0DA to be the colour of text, use `color: #D8F0DA`

Comment: Well, technically he did override it with `background: transparent`.

Comment: But sometimes, that transparent is ignored. Happened with me a few times.

Comment: How can I make the cell's background transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property "background-color: transparent;", or use apha on rgba color representation. Example: "background-color: rgba(216,240,218,0);"

The apha is the last value. It is a decimal number that goes from 0 (totally transparent) to 1 (totally visible).

Answer (score 0):

Just set the opacity for the inner table. You can do inline CSS if you want it just for a specific table element, so it doesn't apply to the entire table.

```
style="opacity: 0%;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
  @media print {
    .table td,
    .table th {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;

    }
}
```