# HTML Table Footer Unable To Span Across All Columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, jinja2

WARNING:  Yes, colors are not the best. This was what was requested/part of my company's colors. Maybe one day it will change, but for now it is what it is. (If you are aware of a way to make them more transparent I am open to fixing that, too! I'm not sure of the [RGBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28142391/10474024) for these colors though.)

I've tried colspan to no avail. I've tried with and without  ... Nothing seems to work. Here is the only two options I seem to be able to setup:

[image: Closest Visual I Can Get]

Below is the Jinja used to create the HTML displayed.

```
jinja_tmplt = """<style>
        table.greenCisco {
          border: 2px solid #005C21;
          background-color: #6CC04A;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: #ABC233;
        }
        tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #6CC04A;
        }
        table.greenCisco td, table.greenCisco th {
          border: 2px solid #000000;
          padding: 3px 2px;
        }
        table.greenCisco tbody td {
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        table.greenCisco thead {
          background: #005C21;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #444444;
        }
        table.greenCisco thead th {
          font-size: 15px;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #FFFFFF;
          text-align: center;
          border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
        }
        table.blueTable tfoot {
          font-size: 13px;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #FFFFFF;
          background: #D0E4F5;
          text-align: center;
          border-top: 2px solid #444444;
        }
    </style>
{% for html_CI in html_CI_list %}
    {% set columns = html_CI.tech_DF.columns.values[1:] %}
    <h1>{{ html_CI.tech_grp }}</h1><br/>
    <table class="greenCisco">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            {% for col_hdr in columns %}
                <th>{{ col_hdr }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in html_CI.tech_DF.itertuples() %}
                {% set row_num = loop.index0 %}
                {% if row_num % 2 == 0 %}
                    <tr bgcolor="#ABC233">
                {% else %}
                    <tr bgcolor="#6CC04A">
                {% endif %}
                {% for elem_data in row[2:] %}
                    {% set loop_num = loop.index0 %}
                    {% if loop_num == 0 %}
                        <td>{{ elem_data }}</td>
                    {% else %}
                        {% if elem_data == 0 %}
                            <td><div style="color:white; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</div></td>
                        {% elif elem_data == 1 %}
                            <td><div style="color:yellow; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</div></td>
                        {% elif elem_data == 2 %}
                            <td><div style="color:green; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</div></td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot valign="center">
            <tr colspan="0" style="width: 100%"><span style="color:white; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</span> <b>Pending</b> <span style="color:yellow; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</span> <b>In Progress</b> <span style="color:green; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</span> <b>Complete</b></tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
{% endfor %}"""
```

I've also tried adding "display: flex; flex-direction:column;" to the style of the footer but no changes.

[image: Using TD tags]

The above is when I add the TD tag - regardless of the colspan.

I am not an HTML expert, I grew up on MySpace and have pieced together things I've needed over the years. This one I'm stumped on!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It may help with debugging if you provide us with the rendered HTML as well.

Comment: Can't do that. Sensitive information. If you can read Jinja you can see what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a TD in the table footer. And then use a colspan = 2 in that TD. 
I got your code and cleaned it to leave only HTML and CSS. I removed the logic in the tbody. The footer had this code here:

```
<table class="greenCisco">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Col one</th>
            <th>Col two</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr bgcolor="#ABC233">

            <td>2</td>
               <td>
                  <div style="color:yellow; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">300</div>
                </td>


            </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot valign="center">
        <tr  style="width: 100%">
            <td colspan="2"><span style="color:white; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</span> 
             <b>Pending</b> <span style="color:yellow; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</span> <b>In Progress</b> <span style="color:green; text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black; font-size: 30px;">&#10003;</span> <b>Complete</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

And this is what it gave me in the browser:
[image]

Comment: This does not work. I tried using TD as already outlined above and it just added a line to the cell. Changing colspan to 2 does nothing when sent via email still. Also - colspan 2 should not work because I have more than 2 columns and colspan is SUPPOSED TO spread across that number of columns (2 or whatever). So the 2 cannot work for my example.

Comment: Okay,then, get rid of the logic in the tbody, no loops, just use an ordinary HTML table with sample data, even two rows, and then that will lead us to the correct the footer and get the table we want.

Comment: Adding the following to the style at least removes the border though:  tfoot, td { border: none; font-style: italic; }

Comment: I cannot use sample data. You could just as easily create a table with the same number of columns and get the same outcome. I'm not understanding what the point is when I've already given the HTML that I am using.